# what is the problem with my path inside CString?

Tags: visual-c++

Why this code does not work? :(

```
  CString parameterA = _T("c:\Program Files\test\identify.exe");  
  CString parameterB = _T(" -format \"%w\" ") + pictureName;

  if (CreateProcess(parameterA.GetBuffer(), parameterB.GetBuffer(),0,0,TRUE,
          NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS|CREATE_NO_WINDOW,0,0,&sInfo,&pInfo))
          {
            WaitForSingleObject (pInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
          }
```

But, when I change the....

```
CString parameterA = _T("c:\Program Files\test\identify.exe");
```

to..

```
CString parameterA = _T("identify.exe");
```

it just works.

Help me..

Comment: Why are you posting same questions  dozen times? Delete all except one, and post your problem completely in one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the slashes.

```
CString parameterA = _T("c:\Program Files\test\identify.exe");
```

Note that you have the escape sequences `\P`, `\t` and `\i`, only one of which actually means something (`\t` is a tab character, and is not what you really want!).

Instead, escape the slashes so they get interpreted as slashes:

```
CString parameterA = _T("c:\\Program Files\\test\\identify.exe");
```